# How to clean build using self-hosted agent when queuing

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using a git source repo in **Azure DevOps** - what is the [proper way to clean all directories, sources, sources directory, etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops#azure-pipelines-tfs-2018-tfs-20172-tfs-20173). when queuing a new build?

There is UX under **Get Sources** that supports this - but you can't assign your own custom variables for the values - it's a static dropdown for both **Clean** and **Clean options** fields.

[image]

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, your question is specifically about how to optionally clean (with different option) or not at queue time?

Comment: 90% of our builds work fine with incremental builds - just like local development. On occasion we need to clean when we queue - [that's what `Build.Clean` used to be used for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544921/175679). This option was deprecated and there doesn't appear to be any documentation on where this option was moved to - ended up [tracking down the build agent source to resolve](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled [across this docs posting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops), but it [states `Build.Clean` is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#buildclean) - but the docs aren't clear that `Build.Repository.Clean` is now the successor. This is what seemed to work for me:

#### Clean Sources Only

[image]

> **Note**: I can confirm `Build.Clean = true` doesn't work anymore.

The [DevOps self-hosted agent is OSS](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent) - so [I was able to confirm support for this undocumented flow using `Build.Repository.Clean`](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/src/Agent.Worker/Build/BuildJobExtension.cs#L162). I don't believe there is a way to assign the clean options at queue-time though.