# Assign build clean option at queue time

Tags: azure-devops

i have a bitbucket classic build pipeline and i need to have the ability to set the build clean option at queue time.  it seems like this used to be possible via the `Build.Clean` variable but that has since been deprecated.

When editing a build pipeline the Clean option uses an editable drop down but anytime you try and type something, it erases what you just wrote.  i would like to set this option to a variable like `$(CleanBuild)`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assign build clean option at queue time

Indeed, the variable `Build.Clean` is already deprecated. But the document [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#build-variables) provided another variable `Build.Repository.Clean`, which will help us to clean the **Sources**:

[image]

Besides, if you want to clean other options fields, like `All build directories`:

[image]

I do not believe there is a way to assign the clean options at queue-time. Even if we use deprecated `Build.Clean` variable, we still can clear Sources only.

You could check [the similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719938/how-to-clean-build-using-self-hosted-agent-when-queuing) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  The docs make it seem like that is a read-only variable that tells you what the setting is in the pipeline. it should be made clear that `Build.Repository.Clean` is a direct successor to `Build.Clean`.

I tested it by setting the pipeline setting to False and then set `Build.Repository.Clean` at queue time.  this caused `git clean -ffdx` and `git reset --hard HEAD` to be ran